# Suppressing traceback from nosetests

Tags: python, nosetests

Im writing nose tests and when a testcase fails , i just want the FAIL message as below and output and not the whole traceback. Is is possible to suppress the traceback messages ?

```
__main__.test_name() ... FAIL
```

Comment: Did you find out any way?

Answer (score 0):

It's not really related to `nose`, but rather to how Python `unittest` works.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53310018/1657819).

Basically, you need to put `__unittest = True` somewhere on top of the each file with tests.