# In PyCharm, how do you add a custom parameter to pytest when running unittests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pycharm

I'm running a Python unittest in pycharm. This executes the command:

```
/<path>/python /<path>/_jb_pytest_runner.py --target my_function_test_base.py::MyFunctionTestBase
```

Launching pytest with arguments my_function_test_base.py::MyFunctionTestBase in //tests

I would like to add a pytest option `--tb=1` that I found in this answer: [Make Python unittest show AssertionError but no Traceback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33555891/make-python-unittest-show-assertionerror-but-no-traceback)

I don't know how to do that under PyCharm.

Comment: Why this is not possible from `Edit Configurations` and then add whatever you want to parameters?

Comment: I see `Additional Arguments` (arguments to the test case I believe), and `Interpreter options` (arguments to the python interpreter). But nothing there that lets me send arguments to pytest. Am I wrong?

Comment: `Additional Arguments` are arguments for `pytest` indeed, try it out.

Comment: Ah, thanks Pavel, you're right! I was misusing the argument and it made me think the arguments were not going to the right place. You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering on behalf of comments, indeed Additional Arguments in the Edit Configurations section does pass arguments through to `py.test`. My error was in misusing one of the arguments, obfuscating the fact that `Additional Arguments` was passing on the arguments as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Edit Configuration -> Python tests -> Custom

Additional Arguments: --tb=1

Comment: It produces: `_jb_pytest_runner.py: error: unrecognized arguments:`